# A Groovy way to add element to a list in a map?

Tags: groovy

I have a `Map` of `Int->List[Int]`, and given a value I want to check if it already has an entry. If so, add to the list. Otherwise, create a new list and add to it. Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
def map = [:]

(1..100).each { i ->
    if (map[i % 10] == null) {
        map[i % 10] = []
    }
    map[i % 10].add(i)
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use map with default value:

```
def map = [:].withDefault {[]}

(1..100).each {map[it % 10].add(it)}
```

The default value will be created every time you try to access non-existing key.

Comment: I tried to do this for hours in Jenkins. It works on the Groovy console, but it does not work in a job. The map would always be empty. Removing `withDefault` from the map and checking for the key existence first did work though.